# groovy split exception java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1

Tags: groovy

I have this code to split the line to get key value pair, if value is missing it throw exection.

why its giving execption? what is the right way to split this key value pair line.

```
def lline="name="
def (key, value) = lline.split("=")
```

Error:

```
Caught: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
```

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because `lline.split("=")` returns an array of 1 item `['name']`, which you try and put the first item into `key` and the second into `value`

If you instead use the version of `split` [that takes a limit](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29):

```
def (key, value) = lline.split( "=", 2 )
```

it should work